# Java null point exxception occuring while trying out list view

Tags: android, android-layout

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Not getting anything, am confused!

Java code:

```
package com.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ListView lvAndroid;
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String[] arrAndroid=    {"Cupcake","Donut","Jellybean","Kitkat","Lollipop","Marshmellow","Nougat"};



    ArrayAdapter adapt = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.lv,arrAndroid);
   lvAndroid=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvAndroid);

    lvAndroid.setAdapter(adapt);
  }
}
```

Lv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.listview.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvAndroid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you include the error trace?

Comment: Where is your TextView in Main Activity

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.yourXMLLayout);` missing right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @AnkitaShah yaa....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling method setContentView() in oncreate.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed this in onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add setContentView(YourLayout);
 then,

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item,arrAndroid);
```